# Not been able to update status on linkedIn on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, linkedin-api

I am using following code

```
 - (void)linkedInEngineAccessToken:(RDLinkedInEngine *)engine setAccessToken:(OAToken *)token {
        if( token ) {
            [token rd_storeInUserDefaultsWithServiceProviderName:@"LinkedIn" prefix:@"My app name"];
        }
        else {
            [OAToken rd_clearUserDefaultsUsingServiceProviderName:@"LinkedIn" prefix:@"My App name"];

        }
    }

    - (OAToken *)linkedInEngineAccessToken:(RDLinkedInEngine *)engine {
        return [OAToken rd_tokenWithUserDefaultsUsingServiceProviderName:@"LinkedIn" prefix:@"My app name"];
    }

    - (void)linkedInEngine:(RDLinkedInEngine *)engine requestSucceeded:(RDLinkedInConnectionID *)identifier withResults:(id)results {
        NSLog(@"++ LinkedIn engine reports success for connection %@\n%@", identifier, results);
        if( identifier == self.fetchConnection ) {
        //    NSDictionary* profile = results;

        }
    }

    - (void)linkedInEngine:(RDLinkedInEngine *)engine requestFailed:(RDLinkedInConnectionID *)identifier withError:(NSError *)error {
        NSLog(@"++ LinkedIn engine reports failure for connection %@\n%@", identifier, [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    - (void)fetchProfile {
        self.fetchConnection = [self.engine profileForCurrentUser];
        [self.engine updateStatus:@"Download app from the #Apple #AppStore and #Android #GooglePlay market."];
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }

    #pragma mark - RDLinkedInAuthorizationControllerDelegate

    - (void)linkedInAuthorizationControllerSucceeded:(RDLinkedInAuthorizationController *)controller {
        [self fetchProfile];
    }

    - (void)linkedInAuthorizationControllerFailed:(RDLinkedInAuthorizationController *)controller {

    }

    - (void)linkedInAuthorizationControllerCanceled:(RDLinkedInAuthorizationController *)controller {

    }


    @end
```

I have set up things correctly. It takes me to linkedIn login page and after login to give permissions I get this error

> Failed to load page Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "A
>   server with the specified hostname could not be found."
>   UserInfo=0x81e2250
>   {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://www.devbee.ca/?oauth_token=MY_TOKEN&oauth_verifier=VERIFIER,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=MY_REDIRECT_URL/?oauth_token=MY_OAUTH_TOKEN&oauth_verifier=MY_VERIFIER,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=A server with the specified hostname could not
>   be found., NSUnderlyingError=0x810ddc0 "A server with the specified
>   hostname could not be found."}

What is wrong?

Is it because of

```
- (OAToken *)linkedInEngineAccessToken:(RDLinkedInEngine *)engine {
            return [OAToken rd_tokenWithUserDefaultsUsingServiceProviderName:@"LinkedIn" prefix:@"My app name"];
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is coming from the fact that http://www.devbee.ca is not up and running. I don't know what point in your code or configuration you are referring to http://www.devbee.ca, but that's where there error lies.

I am guessing that in the configuration for your LinkedIn App, you have set the `OAuth Accept Redirect URL` to http://www.devbee.ca, which is a non-existant URL. But that's just a guess, you need to dig around to figure out why LinkedIn is redirecting you to http://www.devbee.ca.

**Update**

It seems that you need to set this OAuth Accept Redirect URL to `http://linkedin_oauth/success` in your app's configuration. It states this in the How To on the [GitHub project](https://github.com/ResultsDirect/LinkedIn-iPhone):

> Most importantly, the OAuth Redirect URL must be set to:
>   `http://linkedin_oauth/success` for the web view's delegate to be
>   notified

Comment: linkedin redirets me to this url because in settings this is placed as Callbackurl. But i have no idea how to set callback url in iphone

Answer (score 0):

Due to URL connection error it is a problem with your redirect url.

Look, the error says: `"A server with the specified hostname could not be found"`. That means that you haven't got internet connection or your server hostname is not found in DNS list of your provider or your server url is wrong.

What you could try. The error specifies the error url: `"NSErrorFailingURLKey=MY_REDIRECT_URL/?oauth_token=MY_OAUTH_TOKEN&oauth_verifier=MY_VERIFIER"`. You could try to open in Safari/Chrome/etc on your Mac the specified url `"MY_REDIRECT_URL/?oauth_token=MY_OAUTH_TOKEN&oauth_verifier=MY_VERIFIER"` and look what will happen. If you see the same error that you should double check your redirect URL. If it successfully is opened that there is a problem with iOS app.